# How can i send notifications with Pushwoosh in an AIR app when the app is running?

Tags: android, air, pushwoosh

I've implemented Pushwhoosh in my AIR app and it works just fine when the app is closed, or in background (I've tested only on Android). What should i do to receive notifications even when the app is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it is supposed to work by default. However, if you would like to change this behavior, you can try replacing the following in your Manifest file

```
<meta-data android:name="PW_BROADCAST_PUSH" android:value="true" />
```

with

```
<meta-data android:name="PW_BROADCAST_PUSH" android:value="false" />
```

Comment: You do receive the notification when the app is running, however by default Pushwoosh ANE does not display an alert leaving this responsibility to the developer to decide and present the alert to the user.

The change in meta-data tag above will turn the default functionality off and your notification will go to the notification center even if the app is in the foreground.